# How to use rails paths in js files for GET's and ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rails-routing

I have a link that toggles description lengths between short and long.

Initially I created it with a call from a js file, i.e. just

```
# /app/assets/javascripts/toggle_length.js
$.get('/toggle_full_details');
```

That works fine. (it uses css classes to show/hide long and short descriptions).

But ideally I want to use a rails route for the link.

Which are (partial listing for relevant route):

```
$ rake routes
    Prefix               Verb  URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
    ...
    toggle_full_details  GET   /toggle_full_details(.:format)  links#toggle_full_details
    toggle_row_shading   GET   /toggle_row_shading(.:format)   links#toggle_row_shading
    ...
    root                 GET   /                               links#index
```

So I renamed my `long_or_sort_details.js` file to be `long_or_short_details.js.erb` and tried using a rails route but none of the below attempts worked, what am I missing / doing wrong?

```
$.get({ "<%= toggle_full_details_path %>" }) 
// Gave: undefined local variable or method toggle_full_details_path

$.get({"<%= toggle_full_details_url %>"}); 
// Gave: undefined local variable or method toggle_full_details_url

$.ajax({url:"/toggle_full_details", type: 'GET' }) 
// Works ok... but not using routes :(

$.ajax({ url:'<%= toggle_full_details_path %>', type: 'GET' }) 
// undefined local variable or method `toggle_full_details_path'
```

fyi my `app/assets/javascripts/applications.js` includes the file with

```
//= require long_or_short_details
```

Comment: `path` and `url` helpers not available in assets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
$.get("<%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.toggle_full_details_path %>");
```

I don't want any user message if the call fails, hence no `$.ajax` and `success:` or `failure:` calls.

If I had wanted additional stuff for success or failure one could use something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "<%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.toggle_full_details_path %>",
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(r) {
    $('span#messages').html('<span class="ok">yes</span>');
  },
  error: function(r) {
    $('span#messages').html('<span class="not_ok">no</span>');
  }
});
```

Comment: can this make some hole in security?

Comment: This was a simple example.  The idea is that down the road I will have dozens of these and this will give me ability to control their routing in one place and keep old urls as valid when bookmarked.  If that is not a good idea I'm open to other approaches to achieve the same means for me and for others that read this.

Comment: you can define global variables in js with path and keep all in one place, i think.

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be to use the `js-routes` gem which "Brings Rails named routes to javascript"

https://github.com/railsware/js-routes

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [`webpacker`](https://github.com/rails/webpacker), you might want to check out [`js_from_routes`](https://github.com/ElMassimo/js_from_routes), which allows you to generate [helper methods](https://github.com/ElMassimo/js_from_routes/blob/master/spec/support/sample_app/app/javascript/requests/VideoClipsRequests.js#L32-L33) to make AJAX requests.

If you are using jQuery you could use a [custom template](https://gist.github.com/ElMassimo/cab56e64e20ff797f3054b661a883646) that [targets jQuery](https://gist.github.com/ElMassimo/cab56e64e20ff797f3054b661a883646#file-videoclipsrequests-js), and then:

```rb
resources :links do
  get :toggle_full_details, on: :collection, export: true
end
```

```js
import LinksRequests from '@requests/LinksRequests'

LinksRequests.toggleFullDetails({ success: onSuccess, error: onError })
```

However, you can achieve a nicer API by [using](https://github.com/ElMassimo/js_from_routes/blob/master/spec/support/sample_app/app/javascript/services/ApiService.js#L32) [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios).

```js
LinksRequests.toggleFullDetails().then(onSuccess).catch(onError)
```

Benefits:

- Easily specify which routes should generate a helper.
- No need to manually specify the URL and HTTP verb, preventing mistakes and saving development time.